# Как можно отрефакторить данный участок кода

Tags: c#, циклы, оптимизация, инспекция-кода, рефакторинг

### Постановка задачи (что я хочу получить в ответах - указано в конце)

Задача - предоставить пользователю список всех возможных последовательностей элементов, в котором элементы (тип которых - мой перечислитель (**MyEnum**)) расположены по определенному обязательному условию - чтобы поставить элемент на текущую позицию в последовательности, предыдущие 2 элемента должны быть с подходящими значениями (для этого я использую указанную ниже **myEnumAvailabilityDictionary**)

Последовательность элементов для пользователя в итоге будет отображаться на форме или консоли как строка, состоящая из всех элементов последовательности, разделённых знаком "**-**"

### Описание существующего рабочего кода

Существует перечисление:

```
public enum MyEnum 
{
  nan,
  I,
  II,
  III,
  V,
  X
}
```

Существует утилитарный класс (**ProgressionsUtil**.cs) для генерации списка последовательностей, и различной работы с ними.
Он хранит в себе хранит статичную библиотеку, заполненную списками доступных мест для каждого значения **MyEnum** (доступное место - массив из 2 элементов (также типа **MyEnum**) после которых может находится новое **MyEnum** для которого список этих массивов):

```
Dictionary<MyEnum, List<MyEnum[]>> myEnumAvailabilityDictionary = new Dictionary<MyEnum, List<MyEnum[]>(){
  {MyEnum.I, new List<MyEnum[]>() {new MyEnum[] {MyEnum.nan,MyEnum.nan}, new MyEnum[] {MyEnum.nan,MyEnum.I}, new MyEnum[] {MyEnum.I,MyEnum.II}, new MyEnum[] {MyEnum.II,MyEnum.III}}},
  {MyEnum.II, new List<MyEnum[]>() {new MyEnum[] {MyEnum.nan,MyEnum.nan},new MyEnum[] {MyEnum.I,MyEnum.III},new MyEnum[] {MyEnum.I,MyEnum.I}, new MyEnum[] {MyEnum.I,MyEnum.II}}},
  {MyEnum.III, new List<MyEnum[]>() {new MyEnum[] {MyEnum.nan,MyEnum.nan}, new MyEnum[] {MyEnum.II,MyEnum.II}, new MyEnum[] {MyEnum.V,MyEnum.X}, new MyEnum[] {MyEnum.V,MyEnum.X}}},
  {MyEnum.V, new List<MyEnum[]>() {new MyEnum[] {MyEnum.nan,MyEnum.nan}, new MyEnum[] {MyEnum.nan,MyEnum.V}, new MyEnum[] {MyEnum.I,MyEnum.X}, new MyEnum[] {MyEnum.I,MyEnum.X}}},
  {MyEnum.X, new List<MyEnum[]>() {new MyEnum[] {MyEnum.nan,MyEnum.nan}, new MyEnum[] {MyEnum.I,MyEnum.nan}, new MyEnum[] {MyEnum.nan,MyEnum.I}, new MyEnum[] {MyEnum.I,MyEnum.I}}}
}
```

(на самом деле библиотека значительно больше, не могу полную выложить, здесь привёл примеры заполнения)

В этом классе есть методы:

**Для получения списка доступных элементов** (типа **MyEnum**) **на основании 2-х уже существующих** (т.е. они перед ним)

```
private List<MyEnum> GetAvailableMyEnumsOnPoint(MyEnum prevEl1, MyEnum prevEl2) 
{
  List<MyEnum> availableMyEnumsOnPoint = new List<MyEnum>();
  foreach (var pair in myEnumAvailabilityDictionary) 
  {
    if (pair.Value.Any(x => x[0] == prevEl1 && x[1] == prevEl2)) 
    {
      availableMyEnumsOnPoint.Add(pair.Key);
    }
  }
  return availableMyEnumsOnPoint;
}
```

**Для проверки возможности быть следующим элементом на основании 2-х уже существующих** (т.е. они перед ним)

```
private bool AvailableLastMyEnum(MyEnum el, MyEnum prevEl1, MyEnum prevEl2) 
{
  List<MyEnum[]> availableLastMyEnums;
  myEnumAvailabilityDictionary.TryGetValue(el, out availableLastMyEnums);
  return availableLastMyEnums.Any(x => x[0] == prevEl1 && x[1] == prevEl2);
}
```

**Для получения списка возможных последовательностей** (сейчас он работает только для входного значения равного 2-4 включительно)

```
public List<MyEnum[]> GetMyEnumProgressions(int elementInProgressionsCount)
{
  List<MyEnum[]> definedMyEnumProgressions = new List<MyEnum[]>();
  List<MyEnum> myEnums1 = GetAvailableMyEnumsOnPoint(MyEnum.nan, MyEnum.nan);
  foreach (MyEnum el1 in myEnums1)
  {
    List<MyEnum> myEnums2 = GetAvailableMyEnumsOnPoint(MyEnum.nan, el1);
    foreach (MyEnum el2 in myEnums2)
    {
      if (elementInProgressionsCount == 2)
      {
        if (AvailableLastMyEnum(el1, el1, el2))
        {
          definedMyEnumProgressions.Add(new MyEnum[2] { el1, el2 });
        }
      }
      else
      {
        List<MyEnum> myEnums3 = GetAvailableMyEnumsOnPoint(el1, el2);
        foreach (MyEnum el3 in myEnums3)
        {
          if (elementInProgressionsCount == 3)
          {
            if (AvailableLastMyEnum(el1, el2, el3))
            {
              definedMyEnumProgressions.Add(new MyEnum[3] { el1, el2, el3 });
            }
          }
          else
          {
            List<MyEnum> myEnums4 = GetAvailableMyEnumsOnPoint(el2, el3);
            foreach (MyEnum el4 in myEnums4)
            {
              if (elementInProgressionsCount == 4)
              {
                if (AvailableLastMyEnum(el1, el3, el4))
                {
                  definedMyEnumProgressions.Add(new MyEnum[4] { el1, el2, el3, el4 });
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return definedMyEnumProgressions;
}
```

### Что ожидаю получить в ответах

1. Как отрефакторить крайний метод (**GetMyEnumProgressions**), чтобы он работал для входных значений от 2 до 100 (или больше), при этом был по размерам меньше моего (думал насчёт выделение куска кода в отдельный метод и рекурсивно его вызывать, но не смог додумать как это сделать). Либо как изменить весь подход целиком для получения более лакончиного (визуально менее объёмного) и оптимального с точки зрения производительности кода
2. Ускорение \ оптимизация достижения задачи (получения списка возможных последовательностей)
3. Литература про рефакторинг подобных примеров и чего-то посложнее

Comment: Объясните, а что делает этот код? В чем смысл написанного?

Comment: @aepot дополнил в начале описание постановкой задачи

Comment: Это понятно, а зачем эти массивы? Что делать с этим? Спрашиваю, потому что у вас 99,9% структура данных неверно выбрана, но упорно не хотите говорить, для чего она нужна. Секрет чтоли? Ну разбирайтесь сами тогда, я не намерен вас пытать, дело добровольное. Мне пока непонятно, как я могу помочь.

Comment: @aepot нужно вывести пользователю список строк, где строка - массив элементов через разделитель "-" (элементы должны идти в определенном порядке)
чтобы пользователь мог выбрать в дальнейшем эту строку и использовать в реальном мире для записи на бумагу.
Не понимаю почему вам не понятна идея использования массивов, можно конечно что угодно вместо них использовать (списки или другой вариант хранения данных) - это не критично

Comment: `string.Join('-', myList.OrderBy(x => x.ConcreteProperty))` - получите результат в виде упорядоченной строки `I - II - III - IV - V - VI`.. итд, или что вам там нужно вывести непонятно, слишком огромный вопрос и непонятно о чем, конкретизируйте ЧТО не работает и КАК должно работать, а мы скажем как правильно (не в комментах, а измените сам вопрос).

Comment: @Aarnihauta подправил ещё раз постановку задачи
Всё работает, вопрос один, он указан - можно ли упростить и как-то оптимизировать метод GetMyEnumProgressions, чтобы там не было много вложений if, else, foreach, а был например только рекурсивный вызов какого-то 1 нового метода
Если нельзя - то возможно как писали выше изменить подход, выбрать другую структуру для достижения поставленной задачи, чтобы не было таких кривых вложений (if, else, foreach) как у меня

Comment: Ну так и покажите вы только этот метод, не нужно описывать задачу полностью, не нужно описывать что делают методы. все уточнения - редактируйте сам вопрос, не нужно в комментариях объяснять что нужно сделать. Вопрос в текущем виде слишком большой и непонятно ничего кроме как того что надо отрефакторить метод. Напишите задачу которую вы решаете и добавьте два метода, ничего более.

Comment: @Aarnihauta все нормально он описывает, но да, задачу рефакторинга следует максимально четко конкретизировать. Я чуть позже проанализирую.

Comment: @aepot имхо, слишком избыточно, "существует утилитарный класс...", "он хранит в себе статичную библиотеку которая состоит из.." - это можно было написать проще: "есть класс, внутри поле - словарь" и не описывать че там в этом словаре т.к по типу данных и так всё понятно. Ему нужно просто написать "хочу получить список всех возможных последовательностей", показать словарь и пара методов которые нуждаются в рефакторинге, а не вот это вот всё

Comment: @Aarnihauta это уже мелочи, мы ж не на выставке работ, каждый оформляется в силу своих навыков. Лишь бы в целом понятно было. Сейчас гораздо лучше, чем было в начале. Код запутан, да, но по-моему автор как раз и проситт помощи с распутыванием.

Comment: @aepot да дело не в коде вообще, он и просит помощь с рефакторингом, проблема в избыточности деталей, я не против помочь, но не могу прочитать эту поэму огромную в силу физиологических особенностей своего организма, хоть это и моя проблема, но считаю при создании вопроса тоже нужно думать о том, что если он слишком большой, то возможного ответа он не дождется т.к "чето дофига читать ну его нафиг"

Comment: @Aarnihauta тут в комментах в 2 раза больше текста, чем в вопросе. Вам кажется, что много, на самом деле нет.

Comment: Ваш метод возвращает почти всегда пустой массив, и только с аргументом `3` я получил 1 элемент и  вывод `I-I-II`. Как это правильно отлаживать? Я пока не пойму, что происходит.

Comment: Кажись тут рекурсия просматривается, сейчас поковряю.

Comment: @aepot я лишь малую часть указал заполнения библиотеки (на самом деле там порядка 1к записей и генерируется в итоге около сотни последовательностей для аргумента 4) поэтому возможно мало элементов получается на выходе. Расширю чуть позже её в описании, чтобы получилось больше последовательностей на выходе у вас

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь напрашивается рекурсивный подход. До конца в суть задания у меня вникнуть не получилось, поэтому пытался просто при оптимизации сохранить поведение кода, упрощая сам код.

Получилось вот так

```
private List<MyEnum> GetAvailableMyEnumsOnPoint(MyEnum prevEl1, MyEnum prevEl2)
{
    List<MyEnum> availableMyEnumsOnPoint = new();
    foreach (var pair in myEnumAvailabilityDictionary)
    {
        if (pair.Value.Any(x => x[0] == prevEl1 && x[1] == prevEl2))
            availableMyEnumsOnPoint.Add(pair.Key);
    }
    return availableMyEnumsOnPoint;
}

private bool AvailableLastMyEnum(MyEnum el, MyEnum prevEl1, MyEnum prevEl2)
{
    return myEnumAvailabilityDictionary.TryGetValue(el, out List<MyEnum[]> availableLastMyEnums) && availableLastMyEnums.Any(x => x[0] == prevEl1 && x[1] == prevEl2);
}

public List<MyEnum[]> GetMyEnumProgressions(int elementInProgressionsCount)
{
    List<MyEnum[]> definedMyEnumProgressions = new();
    if (elementInProgressionsCount < 2)
        return definedMyEnumProgressions;
    Dive(definedMyEnumProgressions, elementInProgressionsCount, new List<MyEnum>(), 1);
    return definedMyEnumProgressions;
}

private void Dive(List<MyEnum[]> definedMyEnumProgressions, int elementInProgressionsCount, List<MyEnum> list, int level)
{
    foreach (MyEnum el in GetAvailableMyEnumsOnPoint(list.Count < 2 ? MyEnum.nan : list[^2], list.Count < 1 ? MyEnum.nan : list[^1]))
    {
        list.Add(el);
        if (elementInProgressionsCount == level)
        {
            if (AvailableLastMyEnum(list[0], list[^2], list[^1]))
                definedMyEnumProgressions.Add(list.ToArray());
        }
        else
            Dive(definedMyEnumProgressions, elementInProgressionsCount, list, level + 1);
        list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1);
    }
}
```

Вам суть задачи видна яснее, поэтому сможете дальше дорабатывать, если я где-то промахнулся или не увидел новых оптимизаций.

Comment: Судя по идентичным результатам (списку последовательностей) для 4 значений (входного параметра) после замены на ваше решение в проекте - оно подошло
Спасибо!